# how to get post page with post id in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

i wrote a query to get my posts with DESC order as you see its limitet to show 10 posts per page
but how i can find the post with "pid = 18" in what page?

TABLE:

```
pid, posterid, content
1 , 26 , blabla
2 , 8 , sec balnla
3 , 9 , lollll
4 , 26 , orddddd
5 , 10 , sssssdsd
...
```

PHP:

```
function getComments($poster){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE posterid = $poster"
    $smt = $db->query($sql); 
    $total = $smt->rowCount();

    $result = $db->prepare($sql . " ORDER BY pid DESC $limit");
    $result->execute();
    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $Comments[] = $row;
    }
    return [
        'comments' => $Comments,
        'total' => $total
    ];
}
```

NEEDED FUNCTION:

```
$poster = 26;
$pid = 18;
$posttperpage = 10;

public function getPostPage($pid, $poster, $posttperpage)
{
    $page = '';

    $totlaPosts = getComments($poster)['total']; //70

    $pages = $totlaPosts / $posttperpage; //7

    for($i=0, $i<$totlaPosts, $i--)
    {
        // ?????
        // i confuzed no idead what can i do :(

    }
    return $page; //it must be 2
}
```

Comment: I'm confused, do you want to get the number of the page that would have the row where `pid` is 18? Or you want to check if it's in the current page?

Comment: I  want to get the number of the page that would have the row where pid is 18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `pid` is not necessarily consistent (you might have deleted some rows) you should have another query.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table WHERE pid <= ? AND poster = ?");
$stmt->execute([$pid, $poster]);
$count = $stmt->fetchColumn();

echo ceil($count / $posttperpage);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to determine what page a post is on:

```
$k = 1;
for($i=0, $i<$pid; $i += $posttperpage){
    $page = $k;
    $k +=1;
}

//after loop $page now contains what page the post is on.
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: You can accomplish that with a simple math instead of a loop, and still it won't be correct since the `pid`s are not guaranteed to be consistent.

Comment: Agreed, but he implied he wanted his loop fixed.   ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

In your `LIMIT 0,10` you have a range of 10 items per page, right? If you want to keep track of which page you are viewing you need a variable that behaves like this:

```
$range = 10;
$currentPage = 2;
$offset = $range * ($currentPage - 1);
```

Inside your query you can change that 0 to `$offset` and there you have it, if you find your result in with this query it means your pid is in page 2, you can also increase the `$currentPage` by 1 if you can't find your result and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This algo is simple,

You need to know the total of row, the position of your specific post and number of post per page.

And you do like this :

floor(position_of_you_post / number_total_of_post * number_of_post_per_page)

so if you have 100 post with 10 post per page and your post is the number 51, you can do :

51 /100 * 10 = 5.1

so the post is on the page 5

Comment: yes it true but when only one man with same poster id was posted but as use see we have different poster so the post number cannot be usable to cuz maybe my second post in row 24 or ...

Comment: Since the `pid`s are not guaranteed to be consistent (some rows might have been removed) this solution will not work correctly. Also, you should `ceil` and not `floor` the result. The 51th item will be on page 6, not 5.